# full responsive lightbox with unwanted white top-bottom left side border when images clicked

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

Folks,
greetings from the sunny Spain.
I have build a lightbox.
Pictures attached show the home and clicked image states where you can see whats the issue about.
Im doing everything I know to try to fix it, and I wonder if anybody fancy figuring out what am I doing wrong.
Theres no fancy in a new bee 500 line code that could have been written better I am sure but, would you give it a go and KILL that white margin on the left? (it shows the same on mobile)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2mXI.png)

Comment: Hi, first, if you have more data to add please edit the question and don't add a new answer.
Secondly, please give the problem exactly with no extra nonrelevant information (Like what is lightbox is used for). This kind of over explaining makes is hard to understand the problem

Comment: Just add margin-left:0 to your html element :\ :|

Comment: Hey Ashish Bhattarai, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

[this is the home state picture where you can browse works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhrQF.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven, .eight, .nine, .ten, .eleven, .twelve, .thirteen, .fourteen, .fifteen {
            display: inline;
        }

        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;700&display=swap');

        /*Eliminates padding, centers the thumbnail */
        
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin-top:1rem;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
            background: white;
            color: black;
        }

        h1, h2, p {
            display:inline;
        }

        .container {
            margin-bottom: 5em;
        }

        .contact {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            margin-left:1.5%;
            margin-bottom: 1.5%;

            font-size: 0.8rem;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 1rem;
            line-height: 30px;
        }

        .email {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;   
        }

        .phone {
            color: black;
            margin-left: 25%;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 1rem;
            line-height: 30px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 0.9rem;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
            line-height: 1rem;
        }

        hr {
            border-style: inset;
            border-top: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;;
            border-left: none;
            display: block;
            height: 1px;
        }

        header, footer {
            margin-left: 1.5%;
            margin-right: 1.5%;
        }

        /* Styles the thumbnail */

        a.lightbox img {
            height: 220px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
            transition:.5s ease-in-out;
        }

        a.lightbox img:hover {
            filter: brightness(60%);
        }

        a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        /* Styles the lightbox, removes it from sight and adds the fade-in transition */

        .lightbox-target {
            position: fixed;
            top: -100%;
            width: 100%;
            
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
            
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /* Styles the lightbox image, centers it vertically and horizontally, adds the zoom-in transition and makes it responsive using a combination of margin and absolute positioning */

        .lightbox-target img {
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom: 0;
            max-height: 0%;
            max-width: 0%;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        }

            .lightbox-target .aboutjobs {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 30%;
            width: 50%;
            height: 5%;
            color: white;
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }

        /* Styles the close link, adds the slide down transition */

        a.lightbox-close {
            display: block;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: -80px;
            right: 0;
            -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        }

        /* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

        a.lightbox-close:before {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 6rem;
            width: 0.2rem;
            background: red;
            position: absolute;
            left: 1rem;
            top:0.5rem;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform:rotate(45deg);
        }

        /* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

        a.lightbox-close:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 6rem;
            width: 0.2rem;
            background: red;
            position: absolute;
            left: 1rem;
            top:0.5rem;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
            transform:rotate(-45deg);
        }

        /* Uses the :target pseudo-class to perform the animations upon clicking the .lightbox-target anchor */

        .lightbox-target:target {
            opacity: 1;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        .lightbox-target:target img {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
            top: 0px;
        }

        .email:hover, .phone:hover {
            color: #C5C557;
        }

        .VLTW {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }
                
        strong {
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) { /* mobile */
        
            body {
                    text-align: center;
            }

            a.lightbox img {
                    height: 130px;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                    margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
                    transition:.5s ease-in-out
            }

            .lightbox-target .aboutjobs {
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    left: 25%;
                    width: 50%;
                    height: 10%;
                    color: white;
                    font-size: 0.7em;
            }

            h1 {
                    font-size: 1rem;
            }

            h2 {
                    font-size: 0.5rem;
            }

            header h2 {
                    line-height: 2rem;
            }

            .contact {
                    margin:;
                    text-align: center;
            }

            .email {
                    text-align: left;
                    margin-left: 14%;
            }

            .phone {
                    text-align: right;
            }

            strong {
                    font-size: 1rem;
            }

            a.lightbox-close:before 
            a.lightbox-close:after, {
            
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Pedro Alerri</h1>
        <h2>Stills & moving image technical production<h2>
    </header>
<hr>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="one">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#AudiT">
                <img src="audi-q3-1-by-marc-trautmann 2.jpg"/>
            </a>

            <div class="lightbox-target" id="AudiT">
                <img src="audi-q3-1-by-marc-trautmann 2.jpg"/>
                
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & second assistant. Gripvan & DDB for Marc Trautman. Stills for Audi</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="two">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#DC">
               <img src="dylantcollard.jpg"/>
        

            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="DC">
                <img src="dylantcollard.jpg"/>
                
                <p class="aboutjobs">Tecnical production & second assistant. Gripvan & Locate productions for Dylan Collard. Stills for Boehringer Ingelheim </p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="three">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#TA">
                <img src="todd Anthony, locate productions, DVLA London (driver and vehicle licensing agency).jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="TA">
                <img src="todd Anthony, locate productions, DVLA London (driver and vehicle licensing agency).jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Tecnical production. Gripvan & Locate productions for Todd Anthony. Stills for DVLA</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="four">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#TWB">
                <img src="the wade brothers-holiday inn-still productions.jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="TWB">
                <img src="the wade brothers-holiday inn-still productions.jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & second assistant. Gripvan & Stills productions for the Wade Brothers. Stills for the Holiday Inn</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="five">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#NR">
                <img src="noromeworldwide-Dannynorthphoto (3).jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="NR">
                <img src="noromeworldwide-Dannynorthphoto (3).jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & best boy. Gripvan & Dirty Hit for Danny North. No Rome album cover</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="six">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#MH">
                <img src="Max Hetherington. Instagram-iammaximilianiam.jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="MH">
                <img src="Max Hetherington. Instagram-iammaximilianiam.jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & second assistant. Gripvan & Plan productions for (the lovely) Max Hetherington. Pictures for JD & Pink Soda</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="seven">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#CD">
                <img src="I only see great camapign-north6-puma-jon johnson.jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="CD">
                <img src="I only see great camapign-north6-puma-jon johnson.jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & best boy. Gripvan & North6 for Jon Johnson. Puma Campaign</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="eight">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#FS">
                <img src="Federicosorrentino. East End Girls. Instagram-federicosorrentino_o.jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="FS">
                <img src="Federicosorrentino. East End Girls. Instagram-federicosorrentino_o.jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & second assistant. Gripvan & Picture farm for Federico Sorrentino. "East End Girls" Mango campaign</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nine">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#DHE">
                <img src="euromillions, david harriman, still productions, wyatt clarke jones.jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="DHE">
                <img src="euromillions, david harriman, still productions, wyatt clarke jones.jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & second assistant. Gripvan & Still productions for David Harriman. Stills for Euromillions</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ten">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#DH">
                <img src="David Harriman. Instagram1 - Davidharriman.jpg"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="DH">
                <img src="David Harriman. Instagram1 - Davidharriman.jpg"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & best boy. Gripvan & Still productions for David Harriman. Stills for HM Government campaign</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="eleven">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#LRJ">
                <img src="Triger-Jajuar-landrover. snapshot.JPG"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="LRJ">
                <img src="Triger-Jajuar-landrover. snapshot.JPG"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & best boy. Gripvan for Trigger shoots. Stills for Land Rover-Jaguar</p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="twelve">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#S">
                <img src="spotify-still.PNG"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="S">
                <img src="spotify-still.PNG"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production. Gripvan for Who Wot Why & Tom Van Schelven. Moving Image and stills for Spotify. Watch it <a class="VLTW" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZoH3mEzmwXQ"><strong>here</strong></a></p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="thirteen">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#K">
                <img src="keane-still.PNG"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="K">
                <img src="keane-still.PNG"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production. Gripvan for Keane. Moving image for Kode Media. Watch it <a class="VLTW" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RmE-Cr72qH0"><strong>here</strong></a></p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fourteen">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#MepeS">
                <img src="Mercedes-Petronas-still.PNG"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="MepeS">
                <img src="Mercedes-Petronas-still.PNG"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & Spark. Gripvan for Locate productions. Moving image for Mercedes-Petronas Shangai. Watch it <a class="VLTW" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aTbojli1Qe4"><strong>here</strong></a></p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fifteen">
            <a class="lightbox" href="#AMSF">
                <img src="Audi main build-still.PNG"/>
            </a> 
            <div class="lightbox-target" id="AMSF">
                <img src="Audi main build-still.PNG"/>
                <p class="aboutjobs">Technical production & best boy. Gripvan for Black sheep studios. Moving image for Audi. Watch it <a class="VLTW" href="https://vimeo.com/272596196"><strong>here</strong></a></p>
                <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="contact">
                <p>
                    <a class="email" href="mailto:pedroagustinlecumberri@gmail.com">Email</a>
                    <a class="phone" href="tel:+0034 619 967 652">phone</a>
                </p>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```